# PyQt: Right to left controls

Tags: user-interface, pyqt4, qt-designer

I need my all controls to be right aligned. so when resizing they should move with the right upped corner of window instead of left upper.
In visual studio, I simply set the Anchor property of any control to right and up. but PyQt has no Anchor or Dock property. Setting `layoutDirection` to `RightToLeft` didn't help.

note: I'm trying to learn PyQt using Qt Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [QDockWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdockwidget.html). This [example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/mainwindows-dockwidgets.html) might also be useful.

Comment: I don't want to dock my controls. I just need to align them from right.

Comment: links are offline as of 2016

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy:

```
# Create a layout
layout = QHBoxLayout()
# create a control
button = QPushButton("button")
# add the button to the layout and align it to the right
layout.addWidget(button, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)
```

Comment: This gives me `TypeError: addWidget() takes no keyword arguments`